# SQL combining Rows in Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a MySQL DB and I'm trying to combine my results. my SQL Chops aren't experienced enough to come up with a way to accomplish this.

the Picture explains my objective and db structure. https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6dCo.png

this is what I was Using:

```
SELECT
      LISTITEMS.ID,
      LISTITEMS.ItemName,
      PROPVALUE.PropValue,
      LISTPROPERTIES.PropName
FROM LISTITEMS
INNER JOIN PROPVALUE
   ON LISTITEMS.ID = PROPVALUE.ItemID
INNER JOIN LISTPROPERTIES
   ON LISTPROPERTIES.ID = PROPVALUE.PropID
WHERE LISTITEMS.ListID = '$_GET[ID]'
```

this Returns 2 rows and I need 1 row (I edited out the 'ID' columns from the other 2 tables).

```
ID  ItemName  PropValue    ListID       PropName
1   item 1    PropValue1        1       Property1
1   item 1    PropValue2        1       Property2
```

**Edit** Desired output:

```
ID  ListID ItemName  PropName1 PropValue1   PropName2 PropValue2
1   1      Item 1    Property1 PropValue1   Property2 PropValue2
```

Comment: How should they be combined? `PropValue` and `PropName` differ. Please post an example of how you want the output to look.

Comment: (By the way, we assume you have already verified that `$_GET['ID']` is a proper integer. Otherwise, your query is vulnerable to SQL injection...)

Comment: Wait, I get it after looking at the image more closely. Does what I added above match your intent?

Comment: There needs to be a button where you can mark a question "Vulnerable to SQL Injection" without writing a comment. =)

Comment: @JordanR - Is it possible that there might be more than 2 value rows for a given property? IE. Does this need to add PropName3 and PropValue3 as needed?

Comment: I've been seeing too many people asking similar questions recently. Do we have any community wiki articles on pivot tables and mysql - and, specially, why you only *think* you need them in most cases? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 3):

Since the property names will differ dynamically, it is going to be far easier to combine them in a `GROUP_CONCAT()` and then separate them in your application layer:

**Edit**: Fixed query to include all your `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT
      LISTITEMS.ID,
      LISTITEMS.ItemName,
      GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', LISTPROPERTIES.PropName, PROPVALUE.PropValue)) AS Properties
FROM LISTITEMS
INNER JOIN PROPVALUE
   ON LISTITEMS.ID = PROPVALUE.ItemID
INNER JOIN LISTPROPERTIES
   ON LISTPROPERTIES.ID = PROPVALUE.PropID
WHERE LISTITEMS.ListID = '$_GET[ID]'
GROUP BY LISTITEMS.ID, LISTITEMS.ItemName
```

This will output something like:

```
ID ItemName  Properties
1  Item1     Property1|PropValue1,Property2|PropValue2,Property3|PropValue3
```

Then in your PHP code, `explode()` the properties first on `,` to get the pairs, then `explode()` each of those on `|` to get the `name|value` key & value.